# Control doesn't flow into createInitialLayout() in RCP perspective Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, perspective, workbench

Problem : As an RCP perspective is being loaded, it reads content from the current saved settings and doesn't reach `createInitialLayout()`.

Expectation : In case the `createInitialLayout()` is altered, the control should update settings with the most recent changes and load accordingly, without resetting or deleting the settings manually.

> Version of Eclipse : Indigo

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about your `IPerspectiveFactory` class. The `createInitialLayout` method is only called the first time the perspective is created or when you do a 'Reset Perspective'.

Comment: Yes, It is called once, when the perspective is created. By now, I do a change and i want it to be reflected automatically, without clearing the workbench that has favorites and preferences stored.

Comment: Sorry, but this can't be done. You don't have to clear the workbench, just do 'Window > Reset Perspective'